# Is there a way I can get five9 java based dailer to work with ubuntu?

Tags: wine, java

I work from home for a call center and the software we use is based on java and is called Five9 or CVV agent. It only works with Windows and Mac but not Linux. I called the tech support and they told me its not compatible with Linux. 
I am determined that there has to be a way for I dont like to use windows that much. 
I tried using wine and also other java plugins like icetea but still cant get it to open. Let me know if you have any other ideals. thanks.

Comment: tried with virtual box or vmware?

Comment: When you tried it in Wine, did you install Java in wine as well beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Oracle Java for Linux in order to make Five9 work. Free open-source alternative Java will not work (including IcedTea). There is a process described generally here: https://linux4one.com/how-to-install-java-on-linux-mint-19/
I can get it to work in PSTN and Gateway mode, but I have yet to figure out how to get the Softphone mode to work. But I'm still working on it. By the way, I think you mean VCC. Not CVV. Hope this helps you SYNQ up through Linux ;-)